# how to make netbeans IDE aware of classes and methods in other projects for code completion

Tags: php, svn, netbeans, phpdoc, code-completion

I am working on a website in php which is comprised of 2 SVN repositories. One repo has classes in it while the other has scripts in it, so scripts in the script repository will make use of classes in the other repository. I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 to maintain the website, and as such each repository is its own Netbeans project.

This all works out just fine on the server, but a problem is that when working in netbeans, I can only get class name suggestions, method name suggestions, phpdoc, etc., for classes and methods in the same project, so like:

Class repo: `class myStaticClass` has some static methods in it, when I am editing another class `class someOtherClass` in the same project, I can type in `myStaticClass::` and netbeans will have a list populated with the static methods of that class.

However, when I am in the script repo, I will type `myStaticClass::` and netbeans has nothing to say about it.

When I reference a class in the scripts repository, netbeans does not suggest method names or display phpdoc for methods. Is there anyway to make netbeans "look" at all projects when it is trying to gather the live data it presents as you type, rather than just the project you are currently modifying?

Restructuring, moving, or in anyway modifying the repos themselves is NOT an option!

Thanks

Comment: I have not used NB with PHP but maybe you could add your class project in the include Path of the scripts project (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#phpIncludePath)

Comment: Great, since it worked, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have to add your project with classes in the *PHP Include Path* of the project with scripts.

Look for this in the Project Properties and add the corresponding folder as shown in the [documentation pages](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#phpIncludePath) of the NB site.